# How to use SSH Tunnel to connect to an RDS instance via an EC2 instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pgadmin

So this is really new to me, so apologies if this is a dumb question.

I have a RDS instance that is not publicly accessible and is sitting in its own private VPC. I have an EC2 instance that is allowed to connect to RDS, but nothing else is allowed to connect to the instance.

I now want PgAdmin to be able to show data from my RDS instance.

I went through the wizard in PgAdmin, I put in the EC2 Instance's Public IP as Tunnel host, the username is `ec2-user` and the authentication is by identity file (using the pem file that I use to ssh into the instance).

However, I still can't connect. In the Advanced tab, PGAdmin asks for a Host address, but complains when I put in my RDS instance's endpoint.

How do I get my local pgAdmin to now access my DB which is no longer accessible to the public internet?

--- forgot to add the error message

```
Unable to connect to server:

Failed to create the SSH tunnel.
Error: Could not establish session to SSH gateway
```

Comment: What error(s) are you seeing? Can you confirm you can connect to the RDS host from your EC2 (Try telnet $YOURHOST 5432).

Comment: Unable to connect to server:

Failed to create the SSH tunnel.
Error: Could not establish session to SSH gateway

^^ hold up I'll also add this to the question

Comment: @mokugo-devops yes I can connect to my RDS instance from my EC2 server using psql. I've also confirmed that I cannot connect to it from outside of the VPC (as expected)

Comment: `Could not establish session to SSH gateway` indicates that your connection to the EC2 instance is not working. Can you SSH from your local machine to that host? Double check the credentials you've entered in the `SSH Tunnel` dialog match.

Comment: @mokugo-devops yes I can, I suspect that I'm putting in the wrong inputs to the form. Is the identity file supposed to be my .pem file?

Comment: there's not really a password for the PEM file right? So not sure what to put in for the password field

Comment: Correct, you should only need to enter hostname (your EC2), username (the username for your instance), port (22) and identity file (the pem). Ensure Authentication is set to `identity file` too.

Comment: right...I've done that? The hostname is my EC2's public IP4 address. As far as I can tell, I never set an user name, so it should be the default ec2-user and the identity file is the pem file.

Something I'm not grokking though is how the tunnel is going to know about the RDS instance's address

Comment: I believe that is on the connection tab, it uses both tabs.

Comment: I see - but that tab doesn't take a RDS endpoint. What do I put in there?

Comment: In the connection tab there should be a field named host name or something to that effect I believe

Comment: yeah but that *expects* an IP address and RDS isn't giving me one?

Comment: Hostname should also be fine as far as I am aware

Comment: It's not, it expects it to be an IPV4 or IPV6

Comment: It does not expect the DB hostname to be an ip address, I use the RDS hostname in PGAdmin just fine. Are you still getting an SSH error? If so, you need to figure that out before worrying about the database hostname.

Comment: As I recall from last time I tried to use SSH tunnelling with pgAdmin4, it won't work if the identity file is not password protected.

Answer (score 26):

To reproduce your situation using a **SSH Tunnel in PgAdmin**, I did the following:

- Launched an Amazon RDS database with:

  - **Public accessibility:** No
  - **Security Group:** Permit inbound access on 5432 from `10.0.0.0/16` (the CIDR of the VPC)
- Launched a publicly-accessible Amazon EC2 instance in the same VPC
- Configured PgAdmin "SSH Tunnel" as:

  - **Tunnel host:** Used the DNS Name of my EC2 instance
  - **Tunnel port:** 22
  - **Username:** `ec2-user`
  - **Authentication:** *Identity file*
  - **Identity file:** Used the keypair I would use the SSH into the instance
- Configured PgAdmin "Connection" as:

  - **Host:** Endpoint from Amazon RDS console
  - **Port:** 5432
  - Database, Username, Password as set when launching the Amazon RDS database

It **connected successfully**.

If it is hanging for you, check that the **Security Group** is allowing an incoming connection from the EC2 instance.

[image: SSH Tunnel]

[image: Connection]

Comment: I'm going against policies here but this is such a brilliant answer, thank! More should take  after this principle.

Comment: Brilliant! Setting the Tunnel Host to the RDS endpoint was key.  I didn't see this anywhere else.

Comment: "If it is hanging for you, check that the Security Group is allowing an incoming connection from the EC2 instance.". This was it for me, AWS no longer selects this as default so you will need to add it in on the ec2/load balancer.

Comment: If you don't want to start an EC2 instance the [7777 CLI](https://port7777.com/) can start a tunnel on demand.

Answer (score 23):

It appears that you wish to use an Amazon EC2 instance with port forwarding to access a private Amazon RDS instance that is in the same VPC.

Here is how I configure such connections.

#### 1. Confirm that SSH works to the EC2 instance

First, confirm that you can SSH into the EC2 instance. You would use a command similar to:

```
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@IP-ADDRESS
```

#### 2. Use port forwarding

If the above works, then modify the SSH command to use port forwarding:

```
ssh -i key.pem -L 5432:RDS-HOST-NAME:5432 ec2-user@IP-ADDRESS
```

This will forward port 5432 on your own computer to the EC2 instance via SSH. Then, any traffic sent to `localhost:5432` will be forwarded across the SSH connection. The EC2 instance will then send the traffic to `RDS-HOST-NAME:5432`. (Replace `RDS-HOST-NAME` with the DNS Name of the RDS database.)

#### 3. Point PgAdmin to the connection

In PgAdmin, refer to the database as: `localhost:5432`

You can, of course, use a different port number in the port forwarding connection. This can be useful if forwarding multiple connections to different databases. However, I like to keep them the same if possible.

Comment: This is exactly what  I needed since I'm also using a corporate proxy to ssh

Comment: Worked! You saved my day sir!