# How to load an existing database dump into AWS RDS PostgreSQL Instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a database dump which I want to load into my RDS PostgreSQL instance. However I'm unable to do so, please suggest ways to do that.

Comment: "I'm unable to do so," - what does it mean? Sadly your question is unclear and lacks details.

Comment: RDS is just a database service, which will give you working PostgreSQL database. Connect to it like you normally connect to your DB Instance and use client tool like "pgAdmin" which will give you many options to load the dump into DB.

Comment: I'm just asking how to load a DB into PostgreSQL instance on RDS. You downvoting without helping shows your arrogance.

Comment: Thanks @Hussain, also how do I enable SSH Tunneling on that?

Comment: Documentation: [Importing data into PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html)

Answer (score 1):

RDS is just a database service, which will give you working PostgreSQL database. Connect to it like you normally connect to your DB Instance and use client tool like "pgAdmin" which will give you many options to load the dump into DB.

Update:

You can't SSH into RDS server like you would do with EC2 instances. If you want to access your RDS via Bastion host and asking about how to SSH Tunnel into your RDS then your Bastion host should be accepting public SSH traffic. Have to update Security Groups to achieve that and should be in a subnet which has public access.

If you want to connect via CLI then follow this link: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-using-bastion-host-linux/

If you want to connect using UI tool like PGAdmin then this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62335972/970422