# how to connect a RDS outside VPC securely?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

we want to our RDS outside VPC openly access, but it is not secure to do so.

Is there any solution to help us connect the RDS securely ?

Comment: launch your vpc in private subnet and then access it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two basic options to access an Amazon RDS database. Which you choose depends on your [Risk appetite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_appetite).

**Option 1: RDS database in public subnet**

For this option, the database is launched in a Public Subnet, with `Publicly Available = Yes`.

To secure the database, you would **configure the Security Group** to only permit inbound access from **your IP address**.

**Option 2: RDS database in private subnet**

For this option, the database is launched in a Private Subnet, with `Publicly Available = No`.

You will need some way to 'connect' to the VPC, and then connect to the RDS database. Options for connecting to the VPC could be:

- Create an [AWS Client VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html), which allows you to connect to the VPC from any location using an OpenVPN-based VPN client, *or*
- Launch an Amazon EC2 instance in the public subnet and **connect to it using SSH and Port Forwarding** (See: [How to use SSH Tunnel to connect to an RDS instance via an EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62324520/174777))