# Risk for a public RDS database on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-rds

I have a RDS database on a VPC which is public with a password.

I have some lambda functions (that are not in a VPC) that communicates with this database.
To be able to do that I had to modify the security group of my database that allows all trafic for any IP adresses.

For me it's the easiest solution, I don't have to pay for anything (NAT Gateway...), my Lambda function have access to internet and finally I can have access to my database locally.

What I did is the easiest for me but I can of understand that to have a public database is risky. But I don't really understand why ? How can someone have the public address of my database if I just keep it for myself ? Should I filter with the IP address or it is not enough ?

Comment: Perhaps a question better suited to https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If your DB is publicly accessible, especially on a well-known port number, then you should expect it to be attacked. One option you might consider is to make it private (in VPC), put the Lambda function in the same VPC, and whenever you want to access the DB from your laptop, launch a small EC2 instance with a public IP and ingress rule allowing only your laptop IP, and use [SSH port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62324520) from your laptop via the SSH bastion to the DB. Terminate the EC2 instance when done. Not ideal, of course, but more secure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will post it on security.stackexchange.com
About the EC2 I'm not sure I want that, I think I would prefer to be it attacked, too much troubles

Comment: Note that attackers don't simply try to steal the data (which, it sounds like, is not sensitive) but also can cause DDoS to you, data deletion/corruption, excessive network out costs to you, and more. Perhaps these risks are minor, but best to at least be aware of them and do what you can to minimize the risks.

Comment: ok ok got it, and the filtering by IP adress is not enough ?