# How to make an IP to allow when running GitHub Action into a RDS Database that you do not allow access from external access to database?

Tags: database, amazon-rds, prisma

This is currently the Prisma action file that runs migrations:

```
name: Deploy Prisma Migration
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Apply all pending migrations to the database
        run: npx prisma migrate deploy
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_URL }}
```

But it fails since I do not allow IP from external usage or from EC2 Instance I have connected.

Is there any other method such as SSH tunneling from EC2 (since I have connected with EC2 to the RDS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other method such as SSH tunneling from EC2

You can follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62324520/6309), using a SSH Tunnel in PgAdmin.

The same idea would apply for Prisma, which acts as a client that needs to connect to a database.
The main requirement is establishing a secure connection from an external network (GitHub Actions runner in your case) to the RDS instance, which is restricted to external access. That is where the SSH tunnel comes in, providing a secure pathway through an allowed intermediary (the EC2 instance).

You would need to create an SSH key pair on your local machine or GitHub runner. That key will be used to establish a secure SSH connection to the EC2 instance. (`ssh-keygen`). Make sure your EC2 instance has SSH enabled and can access the RDS database, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62335972/6309). Add the public key you generated to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the EC2 instance to allow access.
Add the private key, EC2 instance's IP address or hostname, and username as secrets in your GitHub repository settings. These will be used to establish the SSH connection.

Your GitHub workflow should echo the private key into a file, set appropriate permissions, and then use the SSH command to create a tunnel:

```yaml
- name: Set up SSH Tunnel for Database Access
  run: |
    echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > private_key && chmod 600 private_key
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i private_key ${USER_NAME}@${HOSTNAME} -L local_port:RDS_endpoint:RDS_port -N &
    sleep 5
```

When your GitHub Actions workflow runs, it should create an SSH tunnel to the EC2 instance, which in turn can access the RDS database. That allows your database operations to be performed securely without exposing the RDS instance to the public internet.

Comment: The database is using MySQL not postgres, is there anything different in the procedure?

Comment: @n9p4 No, the same idea should apply